# pass a parameter to ref dbt jinja

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I have a macro. How can I pass correctly model name to a ref function ?

```
{% macro count_all_macro(model) %}


SELECT count(*) FROM {{ ref ( {{ model }} ) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to pass to a ref function without {{ }} SO it will look like

SELECT count(*) FROM {{ ref ( model ) }}